# pandas merge on index not working

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes (Series actually) generated by a groupby operation:

`bw`

```
l1
Consumer Discretionary         0.118718
Consumer Staples               0.089850
Energy                         0.109988
Financials                     0.159418
Health Care                    0.115060
Industrials                    0.109078
Information Technology         0.200392
Materials                      0.035509
Telecommunications Services    0.030796
Utilities                      0.031190
dtype: float64
```

and `pw`

```
l1
Consumer Discretionary         0.148655
Consumer Staples               0.067873
Energy                         0.063899
Financials                     0.095689
Health Care                    0.116015
Industrials                    0.181346
Information Technology         0.117715
Materials                      0.043155
Telecommunications Services    0.009550
Utilities                      0.156103
dtype: float64
```

When I try and `merge` them using

`pd.merge(bw,pw,left_index=True,right_index=True)`

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-174-739bb362e06d>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.merge(pw,attr,left_index=True,right_index=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 185, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 251, in _get_join_info
    left_ax = self.left._data.axes[self.axis]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but when I do

```
bw = bw.reset_index()
pw = pw.reset_index()
mrg = pd.merge(pw,bw,on="l1")
```

It works. It makes my code much less readable over multiple iterations of joins however so I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the first version of the code `merging on indexes` to work.

Thanks

Comment: That's interesting, it looks fine to me.  What version of pandas are you using?  Also, you could try dataframe.join()...  bw.join(pw)

Comment: Hi @BobHaffner its the pandas in the ubuntu repository which I think is 0.14.1. bw.join(pw) gives an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'` which is why I was going down the path of merging...

Comment: Ok, shoot. I had forgotten that join was a df only thing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the series into DataFrame then it is possible to merge

```
merged = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(bw),pd.DataFrame(pw),left_index=True,right_index=True)
print(merged)
```

The result:

```
                                 0_x       0_y
l1                                             
Consumer Discretionary       0.118718  0.118718
Consumer Staples             0.089850  0.089850
Energy                       0.109988  0.109988
Financials                   0.159418  0.159418
Health Care                  0.115060  0.115060
Industrials                  0.109078  0.109078
Information Technology       0.200392  0.200392
Materials                    0.035509  0.222509
Telecommunications Services  0.030796  0.030796
Utilities                    0.031190  0.031190
```

Or if the merge is to be performed in a parallel manner (bw and pw have the same index, same number of items).

```
c = zip(bw.tolist(),pw.tolist())
merged = pd.DataFrame(c, index=bw.index)
```

should have the same result.

When you `reset_index()` a series, it turns to a DataFrame (index to column). That is why you can merge after that.